How to upload files to Kubernetes node with `hostpath` storage class?
I have a Kubernetes cluster with one node (docker-desktop). The cluster has a default storage class hostpath and created a PV as well as a corresponding PVC making use of hostpath storage class. The PVC has successfully bound to a running pod.
As I understand, hostpath makes use of the node's file system as a storage location that pods can use to store files in.
My question is how can I manually access to store files to the node's file system so that the files may be accessible by the running pod?
Please find my PV:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mps-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: hostpath
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/mps/

And my PVC
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mps-pv-claim
  namespace: mps
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  storageClassName: hostpath
  volumeName: mps-pv

PS: I am new to Kubernetes so my question may not even be relevant here.

You almost never want hostpath storage.  It does not work reliably in a typical multi-node cluster, since it refers to a directory on whichever node the pod is running on.  If something like a cluster autoscaler deletes the node, the data is lost.  You also don't usually need to manually create the PersistentVolume.  If you delete this, and the manual storageClassName: and volumeName:, does the cluster automatically create appropriate storage for you?

You will need to install kubectl on your local OS and configure it to connect to the docker desktop Kubernetes cluster. Then you can use the command kubectl cp to copy your files to the storage, by connecting to the pod that is already running and has access to that storage.

I actually found out about kubectl cp not too long after posting this. Thanks anyways!

Nice! I'm happy your problem is solved. :)
